# MySQL Trigger: copy auto_increment value to another column upon insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need to copy the auto_increment ID-value into another column upon insert.
I think I need an "after insert" trigger, because otherwise the new ID is not known..?

I tried this:

```
IF NEW.content IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.content = NEW.id;
END IF
```

But it complains:

> Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: what is the name of your table?

Comment: Table-name is 'notes'

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER insert_example 
  BEFORE INSERT ON  example 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.object_id = NEW.id;  Try This.

Comment: What's the point of setting that column to auto increment's value anyway? You can just modify the query that pulls data out to use auto increment's value if it sees that content column is null and your problem is gone.

Comment: Main reason is to search for the ID when 'content' is empty, also this could be done in SQL indeed. Perhaps this is the better solution..

Answer (score 3):

On  this code

```
  CREATE TRIGGER insert_example
  BEFORE INSERT ON notes
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.content = (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
        FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'notes'
  );
```

i did something like this

```
SET NEW.content = (SELECT CONCAT('ID',LPAD(AUTO_INCREMENT, number,'0')) 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'notes');
```

in case you use UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL on the id field... and you may need a custom type of "public" id...

Answer (score 2):

As the OP pointed out NEW.id won't work with auto-increment; one could use the following trigger (use at own risk). Try this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_example 
      BEFORE INSERT ON notes
      FOR EACH ROW 
      SET NEW.content = (
            SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'notes'
      );
```

Comment: Similarly I thought of a BEFORE INSERT trigger with NEW.content = LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1 but I think that's risky too..

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the next auto_increment value is `LAST_INSERT_ID()+1`. See [autoinc_lock_mode for INNODB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

Comment: so you get help from this link and know how to implement?

Answer (score 1):

If you **really need this behavior** for some reason you can achieve it by using a separate table for sequencing and a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger

First you need a simple table for sequencing purposes that might look like

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key
);
```

Then your factual table schema might look like

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id int not null default 0 primary key,
  content int
);
```

Now the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_table1
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1_seq() VALUES();
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(), NEW.content = COALESCE(NEW.content, NEW.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you if you insert into `table1`

```
INSERT INTO table1 () VALUES (NULL),(-1);
```

You'll have

```
| ID | CONTENT |
|----|---------|
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |      -1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbaf/1)** demo

Comment: @kvdmolen Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Answer is: not possible using triggers. I prefer the easier workarounds (see comment in initial question) or I'll have to build it in application layer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is impossible with triggers. The best you could do is that you replace the `INSERT` statement with a `CALL some_procedure(values...)`, and implement the above logic in that. (assuming   you can change SQL on the application side).

Another (but uglier) solution to setup an EVENT, that periodically fixes your records, where `content=NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a bodge, by can you just say

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
AFTER INSERT ON sometable
BEGIN
  UPDATE sometable SET content = NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id;
END $$
```

update the (same) table via a full query, rather than trying to use SET.

or even

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
AFTER INSERT ON sometable
BEGIN
  UPDATE sometable SET content = id WHERE content is null;
END $$
```

(which is sort of similar to Allita's suggestion of an event)

Comment: It won't work in MySQL. You can't execute any DML statement within a trigger on a table on which you have that trigger defined.

Comment: Latter gives another error: "Can't update table 'notes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Comment: Ah sorry. I admit didnt try it. I've used triggers to insert (another) new row, but hadnt tried update just assumed it would work. I can't downvote my own answer!