# MySQL - assign values of AUTO_INCREMENT to another column in a table

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I have the following table:

[image]

Field `id` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. I want the field `user_id` to have the same values as `id`.

First, I have tried to set `user_id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but that can't be done because there can be only one `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in a table.

Second, I have tried to write a trigger that will assign values from `id` to `user_id`:

```
create trigger 'upd' before update 
on 'obligations' 
for each row 
set old.user_id = old.id;
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of OLD row is not allowed in trigger
```

Could someone suggest how to resolve this?

Note: My question is different because it gives OLD trigger statement error, not NEW trigger statement error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger: copy auto\_increment value to another column upon insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959633/mysql-trigger-copy-auto-increment-value-to-another-column-upon-insert)

Comment: set user_id in a `after update` trigger

Comment: @L. Declercq, But my error is regarding OLD, not NEW.

Comment: @guigoz, It still gives the same error with 'after update'.

Comment: but you have to deal with the `new` value since you will hav a new incremented id

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by the creating a trigger, that will be launched each insert operation. look at the following:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_example
 BEFORE INSERT ON obligations
 FOR EACH ROW 
 SET NEW.user_id= 
  ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'obligations' ); 
  end $$
```