# MySQL 8 - Trigger on INSERT - duplicate AUTO_INCREMENT id for VCS

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, database-trigger, mysql-8.0

Trying to
*create trigger that is called on INSERT & sets `originId = id (AUTO_INCREMENT)`*,
I've used SQL suggested [here in 1st block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34393899/4801779):

```
  CREATE TRIGGER insert_example
  BEFORE INSERT ON notes
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.originId = (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
        FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'notes'
  );
```

Due to `information_schema` caching I have also set

```
information_schema_stats_expiry = 0
```

in `my.cnf` file. Now information gets updated almost instantly on every INSERT, as I've noticed..

But, performing "direct" INSERTs via console with ~2min intervals, I keep getting not updated `AUTO_INCREMENT` values in `originId`.
[image: table example after couple INSERTs]
<sup>(They shoud be equal to `id` fields)</sup>
While explicit queries, fetching AUTO_) result in updated correct values.

Thus I suspect that the result of `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT...` subquery gets somehow.. what? cached?
How can one get around this?

Thank you.

---

### Edit 1

I intended to implement sort of VCS this way:

1. User *creates* new Note, app marks it as 'new' and performs an INSERT in MySQL table. It is the "origin" note.
2. Then user might *edit* this Note (completely) in UI, app will mark is as 'update' and INSERT it in MySQL table as a new row, again. But this time `originId` should be filled with an `id` of "origin" Note (by app logics). And so on.
3. This allows PARTITIONing by `originId` on SELECT, fetching only latest versions to UI.

*initial Problem:*
If `originId` of "origin" Note is NULL, MySQL 8 window function(s) in default (and only?) RESPECT_NULL mode perform(s) framing not as expected ("well, duh, it's all about your NULLs in grouping-by column").

*supposed Solution:*
Set `originId` of "origin" Notes to `id` on their **initial and only** INSERT, expecting 2 benefits:

- Easily fetch "origin" Notes via `originId` = `id`,
- perform correct PARTITION by `originId`.

*resulting Problem:*
`id` is AUTO_INCREMENT, so there's no way (known to me) of getting its new value (for the new row) on INSERT via backend (namely, PHP).

*supposed Solution:*
So, I was hoping to find some MySQL mechanism to solve this (avoiding manipulations with `id` field) and TRIGGERs seemed a right way...

---

### Edit 2

I believed automated duplicating `id` AUTO_INCREMENT field (or any field) within MySQL to be extra fast & super easy, but it totally doesn't appear so now..

So, possibly, better way is to have `vcsGroupId UNSIGNED INT` field, responsible for "relating" Note's versions:

- On *create* and "origin" INSERT - fill it with `MAX(vcsGroupId) + 1`,
- On *edit* and "version" INSERT - fill it with "sibling"/"origin" `vcsGroupId` value (fetched with CTE),
- On *view* and "normal" SELECT - perform framing with Window Function by `PARTITION BY vcsGroupId`, `ORDER BY id` or timestamp `DESC`, then just using 1st (or ascending order by & using last) row,
- On *view* and "origin" SELECT - almost the same, but reversed..

It seems easier, doesn't it?

Comment: Is there any good reason, why you try to "duplicate" the id?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, attempting to implement VCS of sort, I need to duplicate `id` for "origin" notes..

Comment: If the versioning is managed by the application, then why don't you just copy the id in an UPDATE statement after the initial INSERT?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I wasn't sure about implementing this with chained queries _I had to_ execute (INSERT - SELECT id - UPDATE), as I supposed recently. Tripling queries seemed extremely ineffective in terms of performance. Shame on me, as I'd forgotten that PHP allows [getting `id` on every INSERT using Mysqli class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php#102299), not Mysqli_stmt as of prepared queries.. Still, doubling queries remains.. On the other hand, getting "origin" rows via `WHERE id = originId` seems much easier & faster, than partitioning, sorting & picking..isn't it?

Comment: Your design (one row per version) is not very performance friendly. So I wouldn't care much about two queries for the initial insert.

Comment: Do you suggest there is more performance friendly design that stores all fields at all versions?

Comment: For read performance - Yes: One row per item in the base table! The history/diffs can be in a separate table. Usually people rarely want to see previous versions. But that depends on how your app is going to be used. However - "This allows PARTITIONing by originId on SELECT, fetching only latest versions to UI" - This doesn't sound performant. At least when you can have many versions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is playing with fire. I don't know exactly what can go wrong with your trigger (beside that it doesn't work for you already), but I have a strong feeling that many things can and will go wrong. For example: What if you insert multiple rows in a single statement? I don't think, that the engine will update the `information_schema` for each row. And it's going to be even worse if you run an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. So using the `information_schema` for this task is a very bad idea.

However - The first question is: Why do you need it at all? If you need to save the "origin ID", then you probably plan to update the `id` column. That is already a bad idea. And assuming you will find a way to solve your problem - What guarantees you, that the `originId` will not be changed outside the trigger?

However - the alternative is to keep the `originId` column blank on insert, and update it in an UPDATE trigger instead.

Assuming this is your table:

```
create table vcs_test(
  id int auto_increment,
  origin_id int null default null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

Use the UPDATE trigger to save the origin ID, when it is changed for the first time:

```
delimiter //
create trigger vcs_test_before_update before update on vcs_test for each row begin
  if new.id <> old.id then
    set new.origin_id = coalesce(old.origin_id, old.id);
  end if;
end;
delimiter //
```

Your SELECT query would then be something like this:

```
select *, coalesce(origin_id, id) as origin_id from vcs_test;
```

See [demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLDiNJnTuta1TGJpyY57FE/0)

You can even save the full id history with the following schema:

```
create table vcs_test(
  id int auto_increment,
  id_history text null default null,
  primary key (id)
);


delimiter //
create trigger vcs_test_before_update before update on vcs_test for each row begin
  if new.id <> old.id then
    set new.id_history = concat_ws(',', old.id_history, old.id);
  end if;
end;
delimiter //
```

The following test

```
insert into vcs_test (id) values (null), (null), (null);

update vcs_test set id = 5 where id = 2;
update vcs_test set id = 4 where id = 5;

select *, concat_ws(',', id_history, id) as full_id_history
from vcs_test;
```

will return

```
| id  | id_history | full_id_history |
| --- | ---------- | --------------- |
| 1   |            | 1               |
| 3   |            | 3               |
| 4   | 2,5        | 2,5,4           |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hVeinMyywCrnTXHuX4zPs/0)

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer, but "...then you probably plan to update the `id` column..." - isn't what i planned, actually. My intention is to "replace" UPDATE operations with INSERTS. Please, see edit in question.